# Use of localStorage and checkbox(switch)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

first of all. I very appreciate your help. I am a very beginner of JS so please don't laugh even this is a silly question. What I want to do is using the ios style switch in my application and I want them to keep the value as it is set. For example, if a user switched off then the switch should stay off even I reload the page. I have prepared some code below

HTML

```
 <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

 <input id="toggle-one" checked type="checkbox">
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(function() {
 $('#toggle-one').bootstrapToggle();
  })
</script>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: There are already a lot the same question as you're asking here on SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931108/use-localstorage-to-save-a-checkbox-value

Comment: i had already look that it but didnot quite understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  if(localStorage){
    $('#toggle-one').prop("checked",localStorage["ck"]==1);
  }
  $("#toggle-one").on("change",function(e){
    window.localStorage["ck"] = e.target.checked?1:0;
  })
})
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/wecifotira/edit?html,js,console,output)